# "JBAS014151: Could not find view "

Tags: java, jboss, javabeans, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

I am trying to run a java application using Jboss 6.0 EAP that was originally developed using Jboss 7.1 AS. But I am running into the following exception msg:

"JBAS014151: Could not find view ... for EJB ....."

can anyone please advise me on how to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently local calls should use "java:global/" instead of "ejb:" according to https://community.jboss.org/thread/215535 . Making that change worked for EAP 6.1 after getting this error.